# XSL-FO, which browsers support it?

Tags: xsl-fo, browser-support

- Which browsers currently support XSL-FO?
- Which bowsers plan to support it and when?
- Are there any plug-ins one can install to add support for it?
- Are there any apps that can render XSL-FO?

NOTE: I am aware one can generate a PDF from XSL-FO using something like FOP but im only interested in direct support.

Comment: I used to use XSL-FO. I don't believe it is being developed anymore. A good tool that I used was Altova XmlSpy and Altova StyleVision that appears to still fully support it: http://www.altova.com/solutions/xsl-fo-tools.html

Comment: Thanks, I find it such a shame it never took off - it is so much better for browsers than say PDF..

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe that any browsers provide *native rendering* of XSL-FO. However, that doesn't mean that you cannot render XSL-FO in a browser.

**You can render XSL-FO in any browser by adding a processing instruction to the XSL-FO for an XSLT stylesheet that will render HTML from the XSL-FO.**

[**Render-X provides an FO2HTML stylesheet**](http://services.renderx.com/Content/tools/fo2html.html) to convert XSL-FO into XHTML output. It converts `<block>` elements into `<div>`, `<inline>` into `<span>`, etc.

Comment: Yeah it seems no browsers do. I wouldnt render my XSL-FO into XHTML though I use XSLT to transform my XML straight into XHTML. Problem is I want XSL-FO as it is a fixed as opposed to flow document.

Answer (score 1):

[X-Smiles](http://www.xsmiles.org/) supports XSL-FO. It is a Java based browser, and uses [FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) for PDF output.